# Making list of first line and everything else from a string

Tags: python

There is a string:

```
str = "first line\n xxxxxxxxxxxxx\n zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

I need to get a list with two elements: first line and everything else:

```
list = ['first line\n', ' xxxxxxxxxxxxx\n zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz']
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
print str.split('\n', 1)
['first line', ' xxxxxxxxxxxxx\n zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz']
```

The first element don't have '\n' if you want to keep it do:

```
splited = str.partition('\n') 
print [splited[0] + splited[1], splited[2]]
['first line\n', ' xxxxxxxxxxxxx\n zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz']
```

And don't name your string `str` because you will shadow the str type, neither your list `list` :)

Comment: but with this '\n' will not be part of first element in the resulting list

Comment: Upvoted. I haven't seen partition before, cool function + good use of it. You may have to adjust it on the old macs where they use \r instead of \n

Comment: @robert king: That true but in cases the string come from a file he should definitely use the universal newline (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) to open the file , if the file was created in another OS  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> str = "first line\n xxxxxxxxxxxxx\n zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
>>> str.split('\n', 1)
['first line', ' xxxxxxxxxxxxx\n zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz']
```

Comment: I think he wanted the \n to remain on the end of the first line

Comment: @utdemir Good point. Normally wouldn't, was just following his variable names. Should have put a notes to this effect though.

Comment: @robert king, you're obviously more awake than I am! I didn't spot that, but mouad's answer accounts for this so use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "first line\n xxxxxxxxxxxxx\n zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
>>> s=s.splitlines(True)
>>> s=[s[0],"".join(s[1:])]
>>> s
['first line\n', ' xxxxxxxxxxxxx\n zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz']
```

using "True" as a parameter to splitlines specifies that it should "keep ends"

Comment: I edited the variable name from "str" to "s" to avoid shadowing. Did someone down vote me because of this